# Comparing Current UserID against Document UserID in Firebase Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Each document contains a 'userID' of the user that created it.

I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks the delete button it will only delete the document if their uid matches the one of the document.

Here's my firebase rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow create: if request.auth != null
      allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userID;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

However even when they match I receive `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Are my rules just setup incorrectly?

Comment: Security rules on their own do nothing yet. They only become active and meaningful when you execute code against them. Please edit your question to show the [minimal code that any of us can run against these rules that doesn't do what you expect it to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In that code, prove that you're meeting the requirements of the rules, i.e. have an `if` that checks whether the user is `null`, be sure to pass the current UID and not some variable that we can't see, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.